# How can I read only the header column of a CSV file using Python?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am looking for a a way to read just the header row of a large number of large CSV files.

Using Pandas, I have this method available, for each csv file:

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv(PATH_TO_CSV)
>>> df.columns
```

I could do this with just the csv module:

```
>>> reader = csv.DictReader(open(PATH_TO_CSV))
>>> reader.fieldnames
```

The problem with these is that each CSV file is 500MB+ in size, and it seems to be a gigantic waste to read in the entire file of each just to pull the header lines.

My end goal of all of this is to pull out unique column names. I can do that once I have a list of column headers that are in each of these files.

How can I extract only the header row of a CSV file, quickly?

Comment: Note that `DictReader` doesn't read the entire file... so you could just use that iteratively over the files required and build a set... I'm done something similar in an answer I've made...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've used `iglob` as an example to search for the `.csv` files, but one way is to use a set, then adjust as necessary, eg:

```
import csv
from glob import iglob

unique_headers = set()
for filename in iglob('*.csv'):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as fin:
        csvin = csv.reader(fin)
        unique_headers.update(next(csvin, []))
```

Comment: I compared this to the answer Jeff provided. This one is running about 5 times faster than the pandas answer for a sample of my data set. I suspect it's because it doesn't read the extra data row (I appreciate the note about DictReader as well). Thanks

Comment: @Andy I suspect the real difference is not really the un-necessary reading of an additional row, but more the overhead of creating a DataFrame to do so...

Comment: May I know what this sentence means ? "unique_headers.update(next(csvin, []))" @JonClements

Answer (score 44):

Expanding on the [answer given by Jeff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24962970/4873972) It is now possbile to use `pandas` without actually reading any rows.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
In [2]: import numpy as np
In [3]: pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=list('abcd')).to_csv('test.csv', mode='w')

In [4]: pd.read_csv('test.csv', index_col=0, nrows=0).columns.tolist()
Out[4]: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

`pandas` can have the advantage that it deals more gracefully with CSV encodings.

Comment: Hi and great tip.  I found replacing `index_col` with `header` got me an additional field name that I was missing.  Otherwise, the rest works perfectly!

Comment: @MarkMoretto I think it depends upon whether you have an extra index column without a header in your CSV or not. If not it is probably clearest to set `index_col=False` as `header=0` is already kind of the default.

Answer (score 27):

I might be a little late to the party but here's one way to do it using just the Python standard library. When dealing with text data, I prefer to use Python 3 because unicode. So this is very close to your original suggestion except I'm only reading in one row rather than the whole file.

```
import csv    

with open(fpath, 'r') as infile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(infile)
    fieldnames = reader.fieldnames
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: This should be the new accepted answer. It's the fastest and clearest method

Answer (score 13):

Here's one way. You get 1 row.

```
In [9]: DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,4),columns=list('abcd')).to_csv('test.csv',mode='w')

In [10]: read_csv('test.csv',index_col=0,nrows=1)
Out[10]: 
          a         b         c         d
0  0.365453  0.633631 -1.917368 -1.996505
```

Comment: This does read an un-necessary row though for the sake of reading the header... but maybe I'm not entirely clear on what the OP wishes

Comment: I appreciate the answer, Jeff. I compared your answer to the one provided by Jon. Both work, but this one runs about 5 times slower than the one he provided.

Comment: @Jon Clements OP need only headers but `read_csv()` doesn't run with `nrows=0` - `read_csv()` needs to read at least one row.

Comment: @Andy if that matter to you then use the other soln. This is the pandas method.

Comment: @Jeff & Jon Clements: I think you could add `header=None` to get headers as normal row - without first row of data.

Comment: @furas indeed - but still creating a DataFrame without need

Comment: @furas that's right. FYI you can do this much easier by just ``head -n 1 *.csv`` in linux

Comment: @Jeff yup... lots more other ways to do this... op asked for Python though, so err... yeah...

Comment: You are both right :) And I was thinking only about solution with pandas.

Answer (score 13):

What about:

```
pandas.read_csv(PATH_TO_CSV, nrows=1).columns
```

That'll read the first row only and return the columns found.

Comment: still create a unnecessary dataframe of the first row

Answer (score 7):

you have missed `nrows=1` param to read_csv

```
>>> df= pd.read_csv(PATH_TO_CSV, nrows=1)
>>> df.columns
```

Answer (score 1):

it depends on what the header will be used for, if you needed the headers for comparison purposes only (my case) this code will be simple and super fast, it will read the whole header as one string. you can transform all the collected strings together according to your needs:

```
for filename in glob.glob(files_path+"\*.csv"):
    with open(filename) as f:
        first_line = f.readline()
```

Answer (score 1):

it is easy you can use this:

```
df = pd.read_csv("path.csv", skiprows=0, nrows=2)
df.columns.to_list()
```

In this case you can only read really few row for get your header

Answer (score 1):

if you are only interested in the headers and would like to use pandas, the only extra thing you need to pass in apart from the csv file name is "nrows=0":

```
headers = pd.read_csv("test.csv", nrows=0)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import pandas as pd

get_col = list(pd.read_csv("first_test_pipe.csv",sep="|",nrows=1).columns)
print(get_col)
```