# Set header of csv using separate text file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to read data from a textfile which consists of newline separated words I intend to use as the header for a separate csv file with no header.

I've loaded the textfile and dataset in via pandas but don't really know where to go from here.

```
names = pandas.read_csv('names.txt', header = None)
dataset = pandas.read_csv('dataset.csv, header = None')
```

The contents of the textfile look like this

```
dog
cat
sheep
...
```

Comment: Have you tried reading the names like this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/53536044/530160 , then passing the names as the names argument to read_csv? See docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: @NickODell not sure I can make sense of that. So there header text file is just words separated by newlines. The CSV file is then a traditional dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably read your .txt file in a different way, such as using `splitlines()` (as you can see from [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22123823/17203221))

```
with open('names.txt') as f:
    header_names = f.read().splitlines()
```

`header_names` is now a list, and you could it to define the header (column names) of your dataframe:

```
dataset = pandas.read_csv('dataset.csv', header = None)
dataset.columns = header_names
```